# Calculated Column to show only Month and Year from formula results?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, date-time

As is, the formula below works perfect for my project.

However, I would like to spice it up by having the results just display the Month and the Year of the "Next Test Date". Also, is there a way to avoid adding by days (example "+365" or "+182") and just add by months??

working with SharePoint Online if that helps.

I assume I need the following added but I dont know how to merge it to the current Formula.

```
=TEXT([Created],” (MMM YYYY)”)
```

Current **working** Formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]>=90),AND([Mil Status]="DSG",[Composite Score]>=75)),[Previous Test Date]+365,(IF(OR(AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]>=75),AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]<=89)),[Previous Test Date]+182)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]>=90),AND([Mil Status]="DSG",[Composite Score]>=75)),TEXT([Previous Test Date]+365, "MMM YYYY"),(IF(OR(AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]>=75),AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]<=89)),TEXT([Previous Test Date]+182, "MMM YYYY"))))
```

---

Also, you can add months & years in date as well.

Example: Adding 3 months to `[Previous Test Date]`.

```
=DATE(YEAR([Previous Test Date]),MONTH([Previous Test Date])+3,DAY([Previous Test Date]))
```

Check below documentation for more information & syntax:

[Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))

Comment: You Sir! are an amazing person!! This works perfect, thank you so much. I will also play around with that other bit you added after I read up on the provided link.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you Billy!

Comment: **Update on that formula.. Here is the revised Formula with the assistance of "Ganesh"   =IF(OR(AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]>=90),AND([Mil Status]="DSG",[Composite Score]>=75)),TEXT([Previous Test Date]+365,"MMM YYYY"),(IF(AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]>=75),TEXT([Previous Test Date]+182,"MMM YYYY"),(IF(OR(AND([Mil Status]="AGR",[Composite Score]<=74),AND([Mil Status]="DSG",[Composite Score]<=74)),TEXT([Previous Test Date]+0,"MMM YYYY"))))))